# Странное поведение дизайнера форм Visual Studio при использовании параметра AutoScaleMode=AutoScaleMode.Dpi

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, .net-4.8

Я встретился с очень странным поведением дизайнера форм Visual Studio при использовании параметра AutoScaleMode=AutoScaleMode.Dpi

Рассказываю по порядку.

Мне нужно, чтобы приложение, написанное на WinForms, одинаково работало независимо от устновки так называемого масштаба (Scale - параметра) в виндовс, что это такое - показано на картинке.

[image: scale parameter in Windows]

Чтобы продемонстрировать проблему, я написал простое придложение, из одной формы с трмя элеметами управления: label, combo box и picture box.

Приложение есть [здесь](https://github.com/junecat/ScalePrj).

*(Оно просто меняет картинку в picture box в зависимости от выбора в combo box)*

Когда у меня на компе Scale установленг в 100% - все хорошо:

[image: 100% scale]

Более того, если я оставлю в приложении AutoScaleMode "по умолчанию" (`AutoScaleMode-AutoScaleMode.Font`), то всё даже будет продолжать работать на компьютере пользователя, у которого установлен Scale=125%:

[image: 125% scale]

Картинка у пользователя будет "мыльная" (что связано, я полагаю, с алгоритмом масштабирования "на лету"), но в ней всё будет расположено правильно.

Сломается дизайнер форм вижуал студио, в нём всё будет примерно так:

[image: scale 125% in VS designer]

Но настоящая проблема начнётся, если

1. закрыть студию
2. в файле  Form1.Designer.cs поменять строку

   ```
    this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
   ```

на

```
    this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Dpi;
```

3. опять открть студию.

В этот момент начинается нечто, что я не могу описать другим словом, кроме как **жесть**.

Отображаемое на экране в дизайнере форм перестаёт соответствовать написанному в файле  `Form1.Designer.cs`

Например, размер формы, который в файле `Form1.Designer.cs` написан как `System.Drawing.Size(552, 331)`

на экране отображается как `1420, 1070`, причем это меняется в зависмости от того, на каком по размеру мониторе открыт проект. (впечатление, что Студия пытается открыть форму на весь экран, птому что чем больше монитор - тем больше видиый в дизайнере размер формы):

[image: жесть]

Также, location для picturebox меняется так, что его вообще нет на форме (у меня любое измерение в location было больше 2000px).

Причем, повторяю еще раз, это не отображается в файле `Form1.Designer.cs`.

Я проверил это на разных компьютерах (на двух с VS 2022 и на обном с VS 2019).

Также, я искал по словосочетанию "visual studio AutoScaleMode.Dpi designer", но наткнулся только на два достойных упоминания источника:

https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/designers/disable-dpi-awareness?view=vs-2022 - здесь описаны общие проблемы масштабирования приложений

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/f126ccc4-1c2d-439f-af8f-0c825a01f51f/how-to-write-winforms-code-that-autoscales-to-system-font-and-dpi-settings?forum=winforms - здесь кто то задаёт похожий вопрос, но в ответе ни словом не упоминается о проблеме, которую я описал.

В связи с этим - два вопроса:

1. кто то с таким сталкивался? есть ли мысли, как с этим поступать?
2. Какие общие рекомендации Вы можете дать мне, чтобы писать Scale - независимые приложения, которые выглядят одинаково, независимо от установленного у пользователя Scale?

Спасибо заранее!

Comment: Версия дотнета какая? У винформ всегда было всё очень плохо со скейлом. Решение - WPF/UWP/WinUI3. Ну или версию скажите, покопаюсь в старых проектах.

Comment: Судя по иконке, это старик Framework 4.x, там надо в манифест прописывать DpiAwareness. А так, попробуйте тоже самое под .NET 6.

Comment: Привет! Большое спасибо, это был Net Framework 4.8. Попробую, также, попробую "свалить" на WPF.